# Prevent my window from flashing when inactiv under short period

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I'm creating av On screen keyboard. To send keys I do following (pseudocode):

```
SetMyWindowTopMost(true)
SetReceiverWindowActive()
Sleep(100)
SendInput(keys)
SetMyWindowActive()
SetMyWindowTopMost(false)
```

I give focus to another application for a short time (~100 ms) and then regains focus. But I do not want it to appear

The problem is that my program flashes every time it becomes inactive and then active again. Can I prevent it in any way, so that it looks like it is constantly active.

Comment: Do you mean it loses focus when it goes inactive and then regains it when it becomes active?

Comment: I give focus to another application for a short time (~100 ms) and then regains focus. But I do not want it to appear.

Comment: You cannot steal the focus away like this.  Read the rules as documented in the MSDN Library article for SetForegroundWindow().

Comment: @Hans Passant - But, my program do this and it works? My program using SetForegroundWindow to move another application to the foreground and then itself into the foreground.

Comment: The 2nd part is what fails.  You cannot put yourself in the foreground when a user is actively using a window.  Which as far as Windows is concerned is what she's doing, it saw a keystroke.  Google +attachthreadinput +setforegroundwindow to find workarounds.

Comment: I read about SetForegroundWindow and in theory you're right. But the fact is that my window actually regains focus after the receiver window received keyboard strokes. I do not know why it works despite it says in documentation that it should not works.
What I ask is that I do not want the user to see that it lost focus for a short period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be handling [`WM_NCACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message for the period of the possible flash. Either prevent the message to reach `DefWindowProc`, or modify `wParam` to be 'true' as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813745/keep-window-inactive-in-appearance-even-when-activated/815609#815609).