# Strange Window Painting

Tags: c#, window, paint

If you resize Google Chrome 3.0.195.21 to a very small width on Windows 7 (I haven't tried other versions), the window buttons hang off the window.

The window size is not extended, and the overhang does not respond to the mouse.

The window's thumbnail preview shows only the part of the buttons that is inside the window; the Aero Peek preview shows the all of the buttons.

The overhang does not show up in Spy++ (as far as I can tell).

How is that done?

How can I do something like that?  (I write C#, but would take a C++ answer as well)

**EDIT**: In case it isn't clear, I'm asking how I can make such an overhang in my own programs.

Comment: This is programming related.  In case it isn't clear from the question, I'm asking how to make such an overhang.

Comment: Someone's gotta say it:  why would you want this?  I'd rather see a window limit its minimum width so that this doesn't happen in the first place.

Comment: Obviously not for window buttons, but it could be useful for something like a status indicator.  Also, I'm curious.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Comment: @Undo: Oops.  I can't easily find the original image.

Answer (score 2):

When resizing windows on the desktop, Windows relies on WM_GETMINMAXINFO message to obtain the size limits, so that the window will remain usable - as per [Microsoft guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511262.aspx),

> [Resizable windows] Should set a minimum window size if there is a size below which the content is no longer usable. For resizable controls, set minimum resizable element sizes to their smallest functional sizes, such as minimum functional column widths in list views.

By default, Windows imposes a constraint of caption bar height for height, and about 100 pixels for width (min/max/close buttons + a few letters of the name). To remove that constraint you should handle the WM_GETMAXINFO message yourself and change the minimum size to whatever is necessary.

An example of the C# code can be adapted [from here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327824):

```
private const long WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x24;

public struct POINTAPI
{
    public int x;
        public int y;
}

public struct MINMAXINFO
{
    public POINTAPI ptReserved; 
    public POINTAPI ptMaxSize; 
    public POINTAPI ptMaxPosition;
    public POINTAPI ptMinTrackSize; 
    public POINTAPI ptMaxTrackSize;
}

protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m )
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_GETMINMAXINFO)
    {
        MINMAXINFO mmi = (MINMAXINFO)m.GetLParam(typeof(MINMAXINFO));
        mmi.ptMinTrackSize.x = 0;
        mmi.ptMinTrackSize.y = 0;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(mmi, m.LParam, true);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

And (while researching this) I've found [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992352/overcome-os-imposed-windows-form-minimum-size-limit) which deals with the same problem. Apparently you need to override `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` too in order for this to work in Vista and/or C#. (Another example I've seen was in Delphi, and didn't need to override the latter message as well).

Comment: This does not answer my question.  I;m not asking how to make a very small window; I'm asking how to make an overhang.

Comment: That just looks like a bug to me - when the window is too small for the buttons, they will overhang... Did you try to implement that and saw buttons get cropped?