# How to resize a Windows Forms form to be smaller than 132x38?

Tags: .net, winforms

When I resize a borderless form to a small width and height, it won't get smaller than {Width=132, Height=38}.

How do I make it smaller?

Comment: Are you asking how to do that?

Comment: @Tim, i want to resize a form to width=50 and height=38. but it resize to Width=132 and Height=38 itself no less than.

Comment: @ahoo Are you trying to resize a form to 50, 38 and it's resizing itself to 132, 38, or you want to prevent the form from being resized to anything less than 132, 38?

Comment: @Tim, Yes i am trying to resize a form to 50, 38 and it's resizing itself to 132, 38

Comment: @ahoo check what the MinimumSize property is.  It might be Size(132, 38) - if it is, make it (0, 0) or whatever you want the smallest size to be.

Comment: @Yoshi I checked. it is (0,0) :(

Comment: @ahoo is there some code in your form that is preventing the resize?  Perhaps the Resize event is being handled?

Comment: @Tim no there is not. i even added a new form to my project, but this problem exist in new form .

Comment: @ahoo Could it be something in your Settings file, or something else set at the project level?

Comment: @Tim please try yourself. add new form and try to resize it to minimum value (0,0)

Comment: @ahoo I did try this myself, and I was able to resize the form to 0, 0 just fine with the mouse, until I set a higher minimum size value.

Comment: @Tim I did try this on notepad window in win7 and still this problem exist :)

Comment: @ahoo what does Notepad have to do with the problem?  If this resizing problem occurs with any application you use (not just the .NET app you're writing), then I'd say it's a system/OS issue, not a .NET issue.  I've not been able to reproduce your issue despite multiple different attempts.

Comment: @Tim all normal applications in my windows and all .NET app forms have this problem. i can resize to minimum until a certain size that only title bar with `Controls Box` and app Icon is showed. :( i want to resize more

Comment: @ahoo I don't think you can do that with Windows.

Comment: Why would you want to resize the window that small?  Why not... minimize?

Comment: @Inuyasha i used the form for a popUp that must be small and did set FormBorderStyle=None

Comment: Looks like a real question to me.  You can do it in the Load event.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Doesn't look like a question to me. More like a sentence.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, your answer worked for me. if your comment was a post, i would accept it

Comment: So basically the OP wants a window that is visible but so small its not accessible to the user.  I really must know.  What is the point of this?

Comment: This is a legitimate question, just not very well formulated. An answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/994189/1019109.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Based on the discussion in the comments section, what you're trying to do may not be permissible in Windows.  The smallest I can make a window is to where just the icon and the controls box is showed.  To make it any smaller you would have to minimize the window, which would essentially make it invisible (though still present on the task bar).

I'm not sure what value would be gained by making a window so small that you could still see it but couldn't access the app icon or the control boxes, to be honest.

**END UPDATED ANSWER**

Check the MaximumSize and MinimumSize properties on the Form.  They are probably set to 123, 38 currently.

You can set them in the designer in the properties pane, or you can set them programatically:

```
Form1.MaximumSize = new Size(1000, 1000);
From1.MinimumSize = new Size(0, 0);
```

Comment: thanks, but i am waiting for a solution. i need to resize my form to any value. of course in the form i did set `FormBorderStyle=None` for converting to a small popUp, so i need a solution for my problem

Comment: @ahoo Best of luck to you.  I doubt you'll get a solution, but maybe you will.

Comment: For what its worth, I needed a solution to the exact same problem (and a legitimate business reason) - setting the TransparencyKey property of the form solved the problem for me. If for some reason this doesn't work for you, try setting the the MinimumSize Width and Height to 1. I'm guessing when a Form Repaints it cannot have a Width and Height of 0, for Focus purposes.

Comment: Default for minimum size is 0,0 but that seems to mean something else than 0,0 so to say (like not lower than the title bar, and not narrower than the sum of the buttons on the title bar), so one must therefore set the minimum size to 1,1 or something small like that, but not 0,0.

Comment: The question is closed, so can't post an answer. Set MinimumSize of the window to 1,1 (not the default 0,0) then you can set the size as low as 16x16