# How do I set a small height to a borderless child form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am generating a borderless child form on button click.  When I try to set the initial form height, it increases the height as if there is still a ControlBox that has to be shown.  If I use a Tool Window border style it will accept any height, but the borderless form will only size down to approximately 30 pixels (no smaller).  My current applicable code is as follows:

```
Dim taskForm As New Form
taskForm.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
taskForm.AutoSize = False
taskForm.ControlBox = False
taskForm.Height = 2
taskForm.Show()
```

How can I set the this dynamically created borderless form to a smaller height?

Comment: Might be helpful: [Overcome OS Imposed Windows Form Minimum Size Limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992352/overcome-os-imposed-windows-form-minimum-size-limit)

Comment: Winforms prevents you from making a window unusable by making it too small.  And yes, it doesn't pay attention to the border type.  You can override that by setting the size in the Load event.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Making changes in the load event seems to be working.

Comment: @HansPassant: Please post as an answer to be accepted.