# Width of the form can not be less than 140 pixels. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, width

I created default Windows Forms Application project in Visual Studio 2012. When I run program then saw that width of form can not be less than 140 pixels. Why? And how to overcome this strange restriction?

Comment: Check the value of MinimumSize property on the form designer property window

Comment: @Steve MinimumSize = 0; 0;

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for a solution and MinimumSize(0,0) didn't had any effect. Figured out, that MinimumSize set to (1,1) actually fixed the problem and after showing my form it was properly sized smaller than 140px.

Column click event on (*ListView*)_csvLv that should trigger a popup dialog:

```
        var topAnchor = _csvLv.PointToScreen(new Point(
            _csvLv
                .Columns
                .OfType<ColumnHeader>()
                .Where(c => c.DisplayIndex < e.Column)
                .Sum(c => c.Width),
            0));

        Left = topAnchor.X;
        Top = topAnchor.Y;

        MinimumSize = new Size(1,1);
        ClientSize = new Size(_csvLv.Columns[e.Column].Width, 100);

        ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks for this is a better solution than the chosen one.
MinimumSize works.

Comment: This solution (MinimumSize = new Size(1,1)) is the most simple and reliable.

Comment: After a lot of time struggling with this issue I finally could solve it with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Users wouldn't be able to use the window's minimize, maximize, and close buttons at that top. I don't believe you can change that behaviour with the Sizable FormBorderStyle. It's a usability thing.

If you remove the border, by setting it to `None` for example, you can set it to whatever you want programmatically by doing:

```
form.Width = [...];
```

You can resize further forms with border types: None, FixedToolWindow, and SizableToolWindow. The ToolWindows won't let you go below a certain amount as well, but None will let you do anything above 2px. You could set it to some value below that, without getting an exception, but it won't do anything.

Comment: In my program the window's minimize, maximize, and close buttons are not always needed, so it does not matter that can not be seen because of the small width of the form.
But I also need that user to be able change the size of the form hovering the mouse cursor to the edges. But this is impossible if FormBorderStyle set to None...

Comment: A SizableToolWindow will let you go down to about 20-ish pixels. Would that be enough?

Comment: Right, yeah, sorry. That's a tough one. [I found this for you!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992352/overcome-os-imposed-windows-form-minimum-size-limit) Let me know if it helps?

Comment: "but None will let you do anything above 2px"... not true. I have an application without border, but it does not allow a size below 139x39, at least unless I set Form.MinimumSize = new Size(1,1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
Autosize  no
AutosizeMode  growOnly
FormBorderStyle  SizableToolWindow <== this one did it
I still can move the form and resize it (width) less tan 112

Answer (score 1):

I never use formborders.. I always like to go with FormBorderstyle.None

To resize, you have to add some code.

Put a pictureBox, add a grip img in it and place it in the corner.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
        pictureBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseMove);
        pictureBox1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseUp);
    }

    void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isHolding = false;
    }

    void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isHolding)
        {
            int diffX = this.Width - pictureBox1.Left;
            int diffY = this.Height - pictureBox1.Top;
            pictureBox1.Left += e.X - curX;
            pictureBox1.Top += e.Y - curY;
            this.Width = pictureBox1.Left + diffX;
            this.Height = pictureBox1.Top + diffY;                
        }
    }

    void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isHolding = true;
        curX = e.X;
        curY = e.Y;
    }

    int curX = 0, curY = 0;
    bool isHolding = false;
```