# Thinnest possible frame

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using visual C#. I want a pretty thin frame for my application.

I tried `FormBorderStyle.None` and `FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle` but I still get some empty unused space in my frame, how can I eliminate that free space?

I have tried compacting the frame but it stays the same.

So in short, how can I change:

[image: Thick frame]

to:

[image: Thin frame]

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992352/overcome-os-imposed-windows-form-minimum-size-limit help you?

Comment: I assume WinForm. Learn to tag.

Comment: Looks like a Button.  It has an extra pixel around to leave enough room to mark the button as the default Accept button, indicated by a black frame around the button.  If you want it flush against the window border then you'll have to set its Location property to (-1, -1).

Comment: @HansPassant No it is a progress bar and in future will also have a single start/stop button. I need a thin bar which will accommodate both. I am good with the width but height is almost twice of what I actually need.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about.  Just change the Size property, it can be anything.  Type it in the Property window instead of mousing it.

Comment: @HansPassant I also tried changing it in property but even that wouldn't work [Image](http://i42.tinypic.com/v63zah.png) This is what happens. The parameters set by property sets the border correctly but the actual frame is still a lot bigger(which would'nt go even if I decrease the size to 5 units or pixels).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hit and trials: [Overcome OS Imposed Windows Form Minimum Size Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992352/overcome-os-imposed-windows-form-minimum-size-limit?lq=1)  did the job pretty nicely.
Thanks everyone for your precious time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the TransparencyKey property to a color and set the Background to the same. This way the form itself will be transparent, so you won't see the empty space beside your button.

Hope this helps.

(And I also assumed that it's a WinForms app.)

Another thing you can try is overriding the paint handler of the window as described [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?681204-RESOLVED-Setting-Form-Size-to-Anything-Smaller-Than-132-x-38). The code is in VB, but I hope you can manage.

Here is the code in c#:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var r = ClientRectangle;
    // Here you can set the size of the form to any given size
    r.Width = 120;
    r.Height -= 1;
    // Here you draw a one pixel black border
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, r, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. Using the above code I can very well change/control the width of the form but it has no effect on its height.
[image](http://i42.tinypic.com/v63zah.png)

I also tried to change background(back color) to Web->transparent but I get this error : Control does not support transparent background colors. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, you may have chosen the only color that won't work... Change it to some specific color, like Red, and also change the Form's TransparencyKey to the same color (Red). This way it will be transparent. But this solution has some drawbacks: the form still will be there, meaning that when you click on it, you actually click on the form, and not the - visible - things under it. Related to the code above: for me - if you change the line to 'r.Height = 30' then it will be 30 pixels tall. I set the FormBorderStyle to 'None'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow it will accept small sizes, but it will have a caption.