# How to create an 1 pixel wide window using C# and WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, window

I would like to create an application that have a small window displayed at the bottom corner of desktop. On startup, the window shall be very small and ideally, just a couple of pixels in width.

Here is the code I used to do it:

```
public partial class DurationT64 : Form
{
    private Size fullSize;
    private Point fullPos;
    private Point compactPos;

    public DurationT64()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var workingArea = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;

        this.MinimumSize = new Size(0, this.Height);
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);

        // fullPos: the window location when it is in full size form.
        fullPos = new Point(workingArea.Right - this.Width, workingArea.Bottom - this.Height);
        this.Location = fullPos;
        // fullSize: the size of the windown when it is in full size form.
        fullSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
        this.Size = fullSize;

        // compactPos: the window location when it is in compact size form.
        compactPos = new Point(workingArea.Right - 30, fullPos.Y);
        this.Width = 1;
        this.Location = compactPos;
    }
}
```

As you can see that in this example, I intended to create a window of just 1 pixel in width, placed closed to the right edge of the primary monitor.

However, I realized that the window doesn't go as small as I was expected. It goes down to 20 pixels wide but no less than that. Please refer to this screen capture image below for example: 
[an image shows that the window is wider than it suppose to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D8fq.png)

I did some research regards to this problem and noticed that there was a solution proposed by Zach Johnson (@zach-johnson) back in 2009. Here is the link to it [Overcome OS Imposed Windows Form Minimum Size Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992352/overcome-os-imposed-windows-form-minimum-size-limit).

However, nether methods proposed in that link (the intercepting WM_ message one proposed by Zach and the SetBoundsCore one proposed by @Ace) works for me.

Can anyone please give me some solution to this question? Preferably, a solution purely based on C#/Winform and does not rely on native Win32 window message loop, if possible.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you tried `this.MinimumSize = new Size(1, 1);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is rather straight-forward, Winforms ensures that the window cannot be made smaller than the system-imposed minimum size of a window, exposed as the [SystemInformation.MinWindowTrackSize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.minwindowtracksize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .NET.  This is a "safety" setting, it ensures that the user cannot make the window too small when he resizes it, thus losing control over it.  Same consideration applies to code.

Bypassing this limit requires no magic, you need to do two things:

- Set the FormBorderStyle property to None so the user cannot resize the window.
- Set the size *after* the window is created.  The Load event is best.

Some comments about your existing code:  be careful about tinkering with the Width/Height/Size properties, you are doing too much of it in your constructor and it cannot work correctly.  In the constructor they don't yet match the actual size of the window.  And will not be close at all on modern machines with high-resolution monitors, auto-scaling to match the DPI of the video adapter is important today.  You have to postpone until the window is created and scaling is complete, the Load event is the proper place for code like this.  One of the few reasons to actually use Load.

And note that your Location property calculation is inadequate, it does not consider the location of the taskbar.  It doesn't work on my machine, I like the taskbar on the right.

Minimum repro:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        this.Width = 1;
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

Do keep in mind that you'll need hawk-eyes to find it back on the screen :)

Comment: Hi Hans, many thanks for the solution to 1px windows thing. I deeply appreciate that you pointed out my mistake of putting size/location related code in the wrong place. Thanks.

Comment: Changing the form's location in the Load event also works to get you the size you specified in the properties, if you do not want to change the size in the load event.