# MS visual Studio Forms application : Can't get form to have less width then 100 Pixels

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

First question here so if I can improve something in anyway please let me know!

I am currently making a "multi-form" application. 
It currently consists out of a launcher bar with various buttons and the launcher bar has a width of 150 pixels (This one is fine).
When the user presses a button another panel will open 10 pixels next to the the first panel with a width of 75. (I wanted to add the current buttons "subcategories" here)

But when calling the second form it keeps setting itself to 100 pixels (Well I think it is 100 pixels since it seems about 2/3 of the first panel)

```
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (activated == 0)
        {
            var new_y = new form2();
            new_y.AutoSize = false;
            new_y.Width = 75;
            new_y.Height = this.Height;
            new_y.Show();
            activated = 1;
        }
    }
```

I stripped it of some additional code (positioning stuff) so if that could cause any problems please let me know.

But my question : How do I prevent the form setting itself to 100 pixels in width and make it the 75 pixels width I want it to be?

Thanks in advance!

Ps . FormBorderStyle is set to none

Comment: do you have autosize enabled?

Comment: @Jacobr365 Ah yeah I got that to false, It might just be hard coded to a certain minimum.

Comment: yes that is what i meant. Also do you have an Auto scale mode set?

Comment: @Jacobr365 Yes I do got the Font one that comes on by default on. Could that be it?

Comment: It is possible. Might be worth setting it to none and seeing what happens.

Comment: @Jacobr365 Nope :( , Still refuses to get smaller than about 2/3 thirds of the 150 pixel form. I added the setting to both the designer properties and the code itself as :
new_y.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;

Comment: Set the size and then change the width. new_y.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100); https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984427(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: there may be a issue because of OS limitations. Here is a possible fix. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992352/overcome-os-imposed-windows-form-minimum-size-limit

Comment: @RyanGunn I've tried that still wont get smaller.

Comment: @RyanGunn Your approach combined with the answer below made it work for me. Separate they did nothing for me but combined it's working like a charm now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the MinimumSize property:

```
new_y.Width = 75;
new_y.Height = this.Height;
new_y.MinimumSize = new Size(75, this.Height);
```

Comment: A combination of @RyanGunn 's answer and yours seemed to work.
The code is now as following : 
    new_y.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, this.Height);
    new_y.Width = 75;
    new_y.MinimumSize = new Size(75, this.Height);

Comment: If you set the the Size property, you don't have to set the Width and Height.

Comment: I figured as much :) I am really just starting out in C# and was just completely confused what was going on so I really just tried anything haha. Thanks for the help !