# Overcome OS Imposed WPF Window MinWidth Limit

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need my WPF Window (SingleBorderWindow) to be smaller than the OS imposed limit of 100 (in may case).

[This answer covers Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992352/overcome-os-imposed-windows-form-minimum-size-limit) but I could not get it to work on my WPF Window.
Using **WindowStyle = None** or using **Windows.Forms** is not an option in my scenario.

How can this be acieved in a WPF Window?

Comment: What is expected result? If you can not set `WindowStyle="None"`, then window size is set to fit 3 control buttons: minimize, maximize and close.

Comment: Control buttons are removed. Window needs to be as small as 30 units

Comment: Apparently, default title bar buttons cannot be accommodated within 30 pixels. The only solution would be to reproduce these buttons on your own.