# C# Getting the window with focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, window, mouse

I'm making a C# WPF application, and every time the users clicks somewhere outside of my application, I want to display an alert with the TITLE of the window clicked. To detect clicks outside my application, I'm using `LowLevelMouseProc`. But how would I get the window that has focus in C#?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I know this is not related to my original question, but how would I get the control focused, as well?

Comment: to the second question: you probably need a function [`GetFocus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - read Remarks on that MSDN page

Comment: Are you sure you only want to detect when the user *clicks* outside your app?  Users can use the keyboard to switch windows too.  You might try looking into the WM_ACTIVATE message: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813356/determine-where-activation-is-going-when-a-form-is-deactivated (Winforms, but the same basic idea works for WPF as well when you get the HWNDs from WPF windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your follow-up question on how to get the control with focus, you can get the HWND of the focused control using [GetGUIThreadInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Note that you pass this the thread that owns the foreign window, not the foreign window itself (the function docs tell you how to to get the thread ID from the foreign window handle).  The focused HWND is returned through the `GUITHREADINFO.hwndFocus` member.

Note that in general, you can't do better than a HWND, because the foreground window is not necessarily a .NET application.  For example, if the foreign window is a WPF window, this will *not* tell you which WPF control within that window has focus, because WPF controls don't have HWNDs.

Answer (score 6):

[GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do it.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I know this is not related to my original question, but how would I get the control focused, as well?